# is there anything like "oncall" javascript method?

Tags: javascript, android

Im developing html5 audio player using js in my cell phone. Everything work find but when i receive a call or place one the audio still playing. Is there any method to detect phone status?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to detect it on android is via intents. As you are effectively writing a website, you can't access the infrastructure of the phone, you'd need a native app for that (or something like phonegap probably).